# How can I declare an "r" in front of "os.getcwd()" to avoid OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument?

Tags: path, oserror

I am getting an "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:" because the path I am trying to write a file is not found by python. I believe, adding an "r" in front of the path will resolve this error.

Here is the original code where the error is occurring.

```
 # write data file
    with open(os.getcwd() + '\\' + infile, 'wb') as f:
        n, d = X.shape
        f.write(struct.pack("=i", n))
        f.write(struct.pack("=i", d))
        f.write(struct.pack("=d", theta))
        f.write(struct.pack("=d", perplexity))
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a *full* and *complete* copy-paste (as text) of the error output. Also please mark out with a comment in your code the line where you get the error.

Comment: And for debugging, have you tried printing out `os.getcwd() + '\\' + infile` before you try to open the file? Is it a valid path?